# SQL - Obtaining a criterion-limited and total count - is a subquery needed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to obtain the number of orders made by each of our customers that has ordered within the last 31 days, as well as the total number that they've ever made. My desired output would look like:

```
count    total    name           customer ID
--------------------------------------------
3        10       Sarah Smith    22
2        8        John Jenkins   15
1        5        Delia Denton   44
```

So far I have the following, which works perfectly for the first requirement:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(o.id), CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS name, c.id AS "customer ID"
FROM orders o
JOIN customers c ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE order_date > (CURRENT_DATE - 31)
GROUP BY name, "customer ID"
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Which produces:

```
count    name           customer ID
-----------------------------------
3        Sarah Smith    22
2        John Jenkins   15
1        Delia Denton   44
```

However, my limited knowledge of subqueries doesn't extend to how I can integrate one to retrieve the total count of orders for each customer that features in this result set. (Essentially the same query but without the date limitation.) I'm not sure whether (or how) I should be using this as a filter somehow on the total set of all orders, or whether the correct thing is to take the IDs returned here and plug them into another query. What should I do? I'm on PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a single pass over the entire table and use conditional aggregation to calculate the count for the last 31 days.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN order_date > (CURRENT_DATE - 31) THEN o.id END) AS cnt_31,
    COUNT(o.id) AS total,     -- now this will count the grand total
    CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS name,
    c.id AS "customer ID"
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN customers c
    ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY name, "customer ID"
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN order_date > (CURRENT_DATE - 31) THEN o.id END) > 0
ORDER BY count DESC
```

All my query really did was to move the logic from the `WHERE` clause into the count for the last 31 days.  And since this new query is over the entire table, the raw count now corresponds to the `total` in your expected output.

Comment: That's perfect! What I need to learn about here is `CASE`. Thanks very much Tim.

Comment: another way is `sum ((order_date > (CURRENT_DATE - 31))::integer) as cnt_31`

Comment: @Scott I gave you an update to filter off zero 31 day counts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was literally teaching myself to answer my own question at the moment when you provided one for me - thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Just as another way, in situations like this, for  postgres version >= 9.4,
 you can use [filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html) clause

```
SELECT 
COUNT(o.id) as total_cnt, 
count(o.id) filter(WHERE order_date > (CURRENT_DATE - 31)) as last31_cnt, 
CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS name, 
c.id AS "customer ID"
FROM orders o
JOIN customers c ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY name, "customer ID"
having count(o.id) filter(WHERE order_date > (CURRENT_DATE - 31)) > 0
ORDER BY total_cnt DESC
```

Comment: It would be interesting it the `filter` in your `having` clause would outperform what my answer has +1